# R.NET and Windows Forms progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, r.net

I have an R function which I call from R.NET in a Windows Forms application (written in C#)... By using the `Evaluate` method of `REngine`.

This function can take several minutes to evaluate as it has a long `for (i in 1:1000)` loop in it. Therefore, at any one time, the progress of the function is `i/1000`. It's relatively easy to print this out to the R console as the function is executing - by simply adding the line `print(i/1000)` to the R script. However, if I want to pass this value dynamically to my WF application, how would I go about doing that?